# Proguard issue while using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I am using Gson in my application and for that, i am using some classes with name as same as the one in using Json. My application works well, But while writing proguard, application crashes, I guess some of the classes are shrinking. 
my error is :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to com.sample.package.GsonClass

Comment: this doesn't seems the proguard error...

Comment: I tried it with out proguard, and it works well

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add these lines to your proguard so that gson class is kept while signing your app..

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: here is the link to the head revision of that file: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
it works for me but when i applied reverse engg on apk, i got all the model classes with not change in members, it breaks the security purpose, isn't there any other option, we can obfuscate model too ?

Comment: I also had to add `-keepattributes *Annotation*`

Comment: I had to add -keepclassmembers class reference.to.your.data.classes.* { *; }

Answer (score 3):

Another reason is: before use

```
List<T> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

you should construct the correct typeToken, like this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
List<T> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString,type)
```