# Android Retrofit 1.9.0 Release Build IllegalArgument Exception issue

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm getting the crash in android retrofit for release build

```
Last parameter must be of type Callback<X> or Callback<? super X>.
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(Unknown Source)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseResponseType(Unknown Source)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
at retrofit.RestAdapter.getMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I tried Proguard rules from this reference [Proguard issue while using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563916/proguard-issue-while-using-gson) and 
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/372 but it's not working

Comment: Does `-keepattributes Signature` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it looks like you have 2 options:

1) Move all the deserialization and serialization models to a specific package and in `proguard-rules.pro` add the full package name:

```
e.g.

-keep class com.mycompany.myproject.mydata.model.** { *; }
```

and then it will work because those files will not be proguarded.

2) You can use the `@SerializedName` and the `@Export` annotations in the data members of your models like this:

```
public class KeyValue {
    @SerializedName("Key")
    @Expose
    private String key;
    @SerializedName("Value")
    @Expose
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

and then you can even proguard the models.

Hope it will help!!!

Comment: what did you try? just by saying this it is not defining anything