# Gson Nested classes are null while using proguard

Tags: java, android, gson, proguard, dexguard

Warning: class 'com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory' is calling Class.getDeclaredFields on class.

After enabling proguard found some issues mentioned below:

1. Nested static classes are null.
2. List of a custom object in a class is null

Already refer the following bugs, but no luck:

[Proguard issue while using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563916/proguard-issue-while-using-gson)
[Using GSON with proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844352/using-gson-with-proguard-enabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by doing three things to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

**First**, makes sure `ProGuard` doesn't change the names of any of your custom classes you serialize with `Gson`. Let's say that you have a class called `Classname`. To exempt it, add this to your `progaurd-rules.pro`:

```
-keepclassmembernames class com.your.package.classname { <fields>; }
```

(Replace `com.your.package.classname` with your actual package and class name)

I had to do this for like a dozen classes. Don't forget to exempt any member variables of those classes that are also custom. Exempt inner classes with `classname$innerclass` instead of `classname`.

**Second**, add the rules that the `Gson` library recommends. [They can be found here.](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) Here they are as of writing:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

**Last**, add in these two rules:

```
-dontwarn java.lang.reflect.**
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
```

These are what fixed the nested `null` issue I had - Of course, after I had done the above steps.